# How do I modify the text of a span element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to modify the text of messages (to upper case), but children elements has to stay intact. HTML is pre-written by third side. How to do it?

**HTML can be like this,** and I need to modify *"text of the xy message"* from each message.

```
<div class="message">
  <span>
<span class="for you">for you </span> text of the first message.
  </span>
</div>

<div class="message">
  <span>
text of the <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> second message :)
</span>
</div>

<div class="message">
  <span>
  <span class="for you">for you </span> text of the
  <img src="http://www.gnutellaforums.com/images/smilies/smile.gif"> third message...
  </span>
</div>
```

**It should be like this:**

```
...
<div class="message">
<span>
TEXT OF THE <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> SECOND MESSAGE :)
</span>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Ah, _"... .children().remove().end() ..."_ was that "magic". Thanks @frédéric-hamidi :)